# Compress a remote folder in Linux

Tags: linux, compression

I'm a Linux newbie and I'm trying to zip a folder which exists on a remote host and export it to another remote host. A quick Google search lead me to tar/gzip and rsync options but I'm not sure how exactly I could use them.

To be very clear I have logged into remote host through PuTTY (SSH) `user@remotehost1` and there is a folder, folder1 (`/u01/folder1`) which has other sub-folders and files underneath it. I want to gzip it and export it to another remote host user@remotehost2. How can I achieve this. Could some on clearly explain me.

Comment: You're asking two distinct questions: How to compress a folder, and how to copy a file between servers. You'll have an easier time finding the answer to questions yourself if you break them down into their component parts.

Answer (score 2):

Compress the folder:

```
tar czvf folder.tgz folder
```

Copy to other host:

```
scp folder.tgz user@remotehost2:~
```

This command copies the folder.tgz file to the home directory of user at remotehost2.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are logged on to the remote host, do:

1. Compress the folder (this will create the archive `folder.tgz`)

   ```
   tar cvvzf folder.tgz /u01/folder1
   ```
2. Copy the folder to the remote machine

   ```
   scp folder.tgz user2@remotehost2:/path/to/remote/target
   ```